# NGINX/JENKINS: It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken

Tags: nginx, jenkins

I've tried at least a half a donzen examples on how to get NGINX working with Jenkins. My most recent NGINX configuration is based on the following example:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Nginx

No mater what I try, Jenkins keeps saying `It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken.` I'm hoping someone can spot what is wrong as I have spent hours trying to solve this to no avail.

Thanks!

```
upstream cicd {
        keepalive 32;
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;

        server_name cicd.domain.com;

        root /var/run/jenkins/war/;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/jenkins/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/jenkins/error.log;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cicd.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cicd.domain.com/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        #static files
        location ~ "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)$" {
                rewrite "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)" /$1 last;
        }

        #user content
        location /userContent {
                root /var/lib/jenkins/;

                if (!-f $request_filename){
                        rewrite (.*) /$1 last;
                        break;
                }
                sendfile on;
        }

        #cicd
        location @cicd {
                sendfile off;
                proxy_pass              http://cicd;
                proxy_redirect          http://localhost:8080 https://cicd.domain.com;
                proxy_http_version      1.1;

                proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
                proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

                client_max_body_size            10m;
                client_body_buffer_size         128k;

                proxy_connect_timeout           90;
                proxy_send_timeout              90;
                proxy_read_timeout              90;
                proxy_buffering                 off;
                proxy_request_buffering         off;
                proxy_set_header Connection     "";
        }

        #optional
        location / {
                if ($http_user_agent ~* '(iPhone|iPod)') {
                        rewrite ^/$ /view/iphone/ redirect;
                }

                try_files $uri @cicd;
        }

}
```

Comment: Not saying that this is it, but did you check if the Jenkins URL configured is correct? Check  Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System => Jenkins URL.
If it is wrong, then you get your error message.

Comment: Actually, this was exactly what the issue was. When I setup Jenkins it was using the IP and then I switched to the domain. Good catch.

Comment: Converted this to an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is not a NGINX problem.

Inside Jenkins you need to configure the Jenkins URL. If it is not set correctly you will get the error you observed.
Check Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System => Jenkins URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I couldn't find the problem but now I remember I forgot to update the URL.

Answer (score 5):

For me the URL was correctly configured. I had to changed Nginx configuration to include some extra headers:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    
    server_name  my-subdomain.main-domain.com; # this is the url domain of the proxy (Load balancer in front of Jenkins)
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ssl_certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/ssl_key.pem;
    
    location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host my-subdomain.main-domain.com; # this is the url domain of the proxy (Load balancer in front of Jenkins)

        proxy_pass http://${JENKINS_PRIVATE_IP}:${JENKINS_PORT};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Linux (Ubuntu) users, please check the /etc/default/jenkins file.

In that file, look for **JENKINS_ARGS** and copy the **httpListenAddress** and paste it in your Jenkins URL.

I am using Nginx with *Lets Encrypt* encryption and my /etc/default/jenkins file is like this **JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1"**

I think you can also localhost:[your port] or 127.0.0.1:[your port]