# Ngnix 1.12/Jenkins 2.151: It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken

Tags: nginx, jenkins, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to configure reverse proxy for Jenkins 2.151 with nginx-1.12.2 on Centos 7.5 server. my Jenkins running on port 8080 with prefix /Jenkins. Using the below nginx configuration file when I go to manage configuration always getting `It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken`. Tried several different options not able to the fix.

tried these two recommendation already, no luck

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy
[NGINX/JENKINS: It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51006973/nginx-jenkins-it-appears-that-your-reverse-proxy-set-up-is-broken)

Looking for some help now.

```
worker_processes 1;
events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {
    log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $upstream_addr '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen 443 http2 ssl;
        server_name jenkins-dev.test.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log compression;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log ;
        ignore_invalid_headers off;
            location ^~ /jenkins/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/jenkins/;
                proxy_redirect http:// https://;
                sendfile off;
                proxy_set_header   Host             $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Port 443;
                proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
                client_max_body_size       10m;
                client_body_buffer_size    128k;
                proxy_connect_timeout      90;
                proxy_send_timeout         90;
                proxy_read_timeout         90;
                proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
          }
        ssl on;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'HIGH:AES-GCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!SSLv3:!SSLv2:!EXPORT:!DH:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!DHE:!ADH:!EDH';
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    }
}
```

thank
SR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reverse proxying using `nginx`, you need to set the `Jenkins URL` appropriately and you must rewrite the headers to match via your `nginx` config below is an example:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the url you use to access jenkins and the setting Jenkins URL are same.

For ex. I access my jenkins via browser using `http://example.com` so I set my Jenkins URL to `http://example.com`. If you set it to `http://<IP_address>` for example you will see the error you are reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution but a workaround would be OS level port forwarding from `80` to `8080`. This is more like a hack.

1. Redirect port `80` to port `8080` for TCP traffic:

   `firewall-cmd --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080`
2. Make the new settings persist.

   `firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent`
3. Verify port rerouting:

   `firewall-cmd --list-all`

NOTE: You can also do a reboot, just to be sure.